# how to select data from table where another column in another table equal to my parameter value?

Tags: c#, sql-server

i am a beginner and i want to :
 - get recivedID from the below table when total quant equal = 0 and the status field in the second table equal to process
[table 1 - stockTBL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGMou.jpg)

[table 2 - recivedTBL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLkOI.jpg)

that mean when all products in this order = 0 and the order status = process
i want to return recivedID

this is my code :

```
SELECT s.recivedID FROM stockTBL s
JOIN recivedTBL r ON r.recivedID = s.recivedID
WHERE r.status = @STATUS 
GROUP BY s.recivedID 
HAVING (SUM(s.quant) = 0)
```

Comment: And does you code work? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to select all receivedTBL records which has no stockTBL asociated.

```sql
SELECT s.recivedID, SUM(s.quant) 
  FROM stockTBL s
  JOIN recivedTBL r ON r.recivedID = s.recivedID
 WHERE r.status = @STATUS 
 GROUP BY s.recivedID 
HAVING (SUM(s.quant) = 0) -- sum stockTBL
```

Comment: Vote up my answer please!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need the SQL code to accomplish that:

```
SELECT T1.recivedID
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.recivedID = t2.recivedID
WHERE T1.quant = 0
AND T2.status = @status
```

Comment: i  want total quant = 0

Comment: what do you mean by total quant?